# "forms of beauty which later became immortal in breathing marble" - breating marble?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading a story by H. P. Lovecraft, I am unsure about the meaning of "breathing" in the following:

> There he would meditate upon the visions that filled his mind, and
> there devise the forms of beauty which later became immortal in
> breathing marble.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that the sculptures were lifelike as if they breath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. It is just a stylistic flourish (not entirely successful in my opinion) to suggest that the statues are of such high quality, they give the impression of life (note 'immortal').